# Get data from local storage and append to html as li?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, local-storage

I'm not really sure what is the right step to do next but right now I have my external json file doing a get request then place it into a div. How do I make each object to be a list item? Instead of looking like this on the webpage? https://ibb.co/cxU4Aa

Thanks!

```
$(function () {
  getStarterMenuData();
});

function getStarterMenuData() { //AJAX http get request
  $.get(
    'data/startersMenu.json',
    function (data) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('starterMenu', JSON.stringify(data)); //Calls local storage API, stores key/value into local storage
    },
    'json'
    );
}

  var data;
  data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('startersMenu')); //Gets the data from local storage
  document.getElementById("starters").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("starterMenu");
```

The external json file looks like this

```
[

{
 "name": "Jumbo Lump Crab Cake",
 "description": "Creole lobster sauce."
},

{
  "name": "Bacon Wrapped Sea Scallops",
  "description": "Chardonnay lemon sauce, Mango salsa."
},
{
  "name": "Chilled Maine Lobster Cocktail",
  "description": "Atomic cocktail sauce and lemon butter."
},
{
  "name": "Coconut Shrimp",
  "description": "three jumbo tiger shrimp, vanilla orange beurre blanc."
},
{
  "name": "Crispy Point Judith Calamari",
  "description": "Italian peppers and Bleu cheese Stuffed olives, Atomic cocktail sauce."
},
{
  "name": "Oysters on the Half Shell",
  "description": "shucked to order, mignonette and Atomic cocktail sauces."
}

]
```

Comment: You simply loop through the returned data, create your html and then render it to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (or a loop) over your data. So do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("starters").html(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("starterMenu")).map(function(data) {
    var $list = $('<li>');
    $list.append($('<h1>', { text: data.name }));
    $list.append($('<div>', { text: data.description }));
    return $list;
}));
```

NB: it's worth adding your text as actual text rather than HTML to prevent XSS.

Comment: Hi, I tried placing what you stated in, but it's saying it's missing an ) after argument list? Here's the screenshot https://ibb.co/kVBZAa

Comment: @BeckyT sorry I missed a comma after  '<div>'. Fixed now

Comment: Thanks! @winhowes, last question, do you know why it comes up as object and not the actual text in the data?

Comment: @BeckyT I fixed a bug I noticed with it. Does that fix your issue? I was doing a `.innerHTML=` and giving it an array of jQuery objects rather than using jQuery's `.html()` function which will take an array jQuery objects and convert it to html.

Answer (score 1):

You simply loop through the returned data, create your html and then render it to the page

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "Jumbo Lump Crab Cake",
    "description": "Creole lobster sauce."
  },

  {
    "name": "Bacon Wrapped Sea Scallops",
    "description": "Chardonnay lemon sauce, Mango salsa."
  },
  {
    "name": "Chilled Maine Lobster Cocktail",
    "description": "Atomic cocktail sauce and lemon butter."
  },
  {
    "name": "Coconut Shrimp",
    "description": "three jumbo tiger shrimp, vanilla orange beurre blanc."
  },
  {
    "name": "Crispy Point Judith Calamari",
    "description": "Italian peppers and Bleu cheese Stuffed olives, Atomic cocktail sauce."
  },
  {
    "name": "Oysters on the Half Shell",
    "description": "shucked to order, mignonette and Atomic cocktail sauces."
  }
]
const myHtml = [];
// loop through the data building up the html
data.forEach(value => myHtml.push(`<li>${value.name}</li><li>${value.description}</li>`));
// now render the html
$('#myData').append(myHtml.join(''))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myData"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your data and create `li` like following.

```
var data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('startersMenu'));

data.forEach(function(item) {
    var $ul = $("#starters");        
    $ul.append('<li>'+ item.name + '</li>');
})
```